# How is Cosmos RU distribution done across containers

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

1)  In a database with shared RUs how does it distribute the RUs across containers. We also know that when creating a new container a minimum of 100RUs are allocated to it. For example if we have 400RUs at the Database level and have 4 container. If 3 of the containers consume only 50RUs and the 4th container requires 250RUs. Then will Cosmos redistribute remaining 50RUs from each of the containers to the 4th container.

2)  How is RUs for partitions allocated. If we have a partition key of userid and have 1000 users in a shared RU database and 100RUs for this container. How will the RUs be distributed across such partition. How dynamic is the RU distribution for partitions

Answer (score 0):

> 1) In a database with shared RUs how does it distribute the RUs across
>   containers. We also know that when creating a new container a minimum
>   of 100RUs are allocated to it. For example if we have 400RUs at the
>   Database level and have 4 container. If 3 of the containers consume
>   only 50RUs and the 4th container requires 250RUs. Then will Cosmos
>   redistribute remaining 50RUs from each of the containers to the 4th
>   container.

According to my research, if we provision throughput on an Azure Cosmos database, the throughput is shared across all the containers in the database. Meanwhile, because all containers within a database share the resources available on a machine, you naturally do not get predictable performance on any specific container and Azure Cosmos DB doesn't provide any predictable throughput guarantees for a particular container in that database. The portion of the throughput that a specific container can receive is dependent on:

- The number of containers
- The choice of partition keys for various containers
- The distribution of the workload across various logical partitions of the containers.

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#set-throughput-on-a-database).